# MultiCore processing with VBA

Tags: vba, architecture, multiprocessing

I know there is no way to thread or anything fancy like that with VBA but when I was recently running a find duplicates macro in VBA on about 60000 lines of excel data I opened task manager performance to find that all 4 cores of my processor were under heavier than normal usage. One core was at about 80% and the other 3 were at about 60%.

This is rather high being as of right now none of them are going over 15%.

So my question is how does my sequential VBA macro get divided into 4 parrallel parts that tax each processor core?

Comment: Some features of Excel can use multiple cores: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514(v=office.14).aspx#MultithreadedCalculation

Comment: While that is something I didn't know and a rather interesting read, I dont think it accounts for this situation. The bulk of my find duplicates macro was comparing cells using if statements. I nested them for preformance so anywhere between 1 and 10 comparisions were performed on each row within a loop. This sounded like it parrallel calculated independant spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: Yes - I suspected that might be the case, but it was possible you were using some worksheet-level calculations so I posted anyway.